# Nested object name

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to know the name of a given object in a class

```
class B {
   abstract class F{
       def name = getClass.getSimpleName
   }
   object FI extends F
}

val b = new B
println(b.FI)
```

With Scala 2.9.1 it prints B$FI$

With Scala 2.9.2 it prints FI$

What I really want is "FI". What is the best way to get FI and be sure that it won't change in future versions of scala? Is there some reflection support to help me?

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you use the fully qualified name (i.e. `getName` instead of `getSimpleName`)?  This might be a change in behaviour of how the simple name tokenising works, which would not be an issue in general since simple names are never going to be the way to reference a class unambiguously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with the new reflection API introduced in Scala 2.10 as follows:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
mirror: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@609a5d54 of type class scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader with classpath <unknown>

scala> mirror.reflect(new B().FI).symbol.name
res24: reflect.runtime.universe.Name = FI
```